# What's the best way to loop this

Tags: c#, for-loop, while-loop

sorry for bad title. 
Code below itself pretty simple and self-explanatory. I basically use the index of an item if it exists. What I don't like is the code below is actually doing the same thing twice (someList.IndexOf).

```
while(someList.IndexOf(something) != -1)
{
 int index = someList.IndexOf(something); 
 //other stuff (someList and something will change here)
}
```

I wonder if there is a better way to do it. I want to use the value (forgive my lack of terminology) inside the loop again,  like using the "i" in for loop.

```
while(value) { //use the value here}
```

Comment: Store it somewhere (a variable), of course.

Comment: what is somelist? what is something? what are you trying to do? what other stuff will change? Could you explain?

Comment: I was actually wondering for more elegant way ,like assigning the variable in while parentheses, doing it with one line somehow. I guess it doesn't exists. Thanks to everyone who commented.

Comment: @Mert, you can assign in the while. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Just set and test in your while loop.

```
while((someIndex = someList.IndexOf(something)) != -1){

}
```

Comment: This has the benefit of reducing redundant code, but at the expense of adding brackets, and... it's already starting to seem a bit more like a Lisp. It's not bad, though.

Comment: I wasn't know that, ty. It would be great if not only assign but also we can identify the variable in while parentheses.

Comment: "starting to seem a bit more like a Lisp." /Shudder Think so? I use this pattern quite a bit, normally with reading from a file. e.g., `while ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)...` YMMV.

Comment: Additionally, most people during maintenance will typically expect that kind of side-effect anywhere else but in that control statement there. You could write `while (stream.Peek() >= 0) { string line = stream.ReadLine(); ... }`, for example ([as Microsoft does in their example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)), and your mileage would likely vary much less. As an added bonus, your variable declaration becomes more local this way...

Comment: Well, Microsoft also follows my example in their article specifically on [How to read a text file one line at a time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time). So, I don't think this is a crazy practice. But YMMV as I say :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try implementing *more readable* `for` loop instead of `while` one:

```
  for(int index = someList.IndexOf(something); 
          index >= 0; 
          index = someList.IndexOf(something)) {
    ...
  }
```

Please notice, that there's no overhead (computation `IndexOf` twice) and everything in the loop declaration and thus you can put, say, `continue` without any additional code

Comment: So this doesn't compute twice even if we set it (index = someList.IndexOf()) twice. And ty. It's weird, I was thinking that the question was stupid before asking still I learn something new.

Comment: @Mert There is indeed no computational overhead here. There may be a slight maintenance overhead (which is really not a big deal, hence my +1 just now), however, if someone decides `someList.IndexOf(something)` needs to change, as they'll need to make that change twice rather than once.

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw in another possible solution. You can add an extension method and make it a little bit more readable without the `-1` magic number in the loop itself.

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static bool TryGetIndexOf<T>(this IList<T> source, T item, out int index)
    {
        if(source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

        index = source.IndexOf(item);
        return index != -1;
    }
}
```

Then your loop becomes:

```
List<int> someList = new List<int> { 5, 10, 15, 20 };
int something = 5;

while (someList.TryGetIndexOf(something, out var idx))
{
    something += 5;
}
```

Comment: Another nice option, moving along this direction, is to write a function that processes one element at a time, and then a trivial loop to call that function repetitively. I'm strangely fond of this (your answer) as it is, though, because of how the usage resembles `type.TryParse` and introduces reference arguments. Nice job turning a vague question into an opportunity to teach someone about some nuance corners of C# that are relatively unknown :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int someIndex = someList.IndexOf(something);

while( someIndex != -1)
{
    // do something to something so someIndex changes

    someIndex = someList.IndexOf(something)
}
```

You are essentially doing things to something until leaves the list. So you could also use:

```
using System.Linq;

var something = someList[7]; // get your item from someList

while( !someList.Any( elem => elem == something))
{
    // if this is practicable depends on your "things" to do to something
}
```

Comment: another missed chance to comment the -1 so  I know how to get better

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = someList.IndexOf(something);
while(index != -1)
{
    // compute values for someList and something
    //other stuff (someList and something will change here)
    index = someList.IndexOf(something);
}
```

Comment: Did you realise that this is an expanded form of a `for` loop?

Comment: @Sebivor the purpose was to answer in a syntax as near as possible to the question. The accepted answer is just a short version of what i wrote.